# After upgrading TypeScript, Angular controller registration now fails to compile

Tags: angularjs, typescript, typescript2.0

We were using TypeScript 2.2.  After upgrading to 2.4, we now get this on compilation:

> error TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof TopMenuController' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Injectable<IControllerConstructor>'.
> Type 'typeof TopMenuController' is not assignable to type '(string | (new (...args: any[]) => IController) | ((...args: any[]) => void | IController))[]'.
> Property 'push' is missing in type 'typeof TopMenuController'.

> ts\controllers\TopMenuController.ts(2,18): error TS2559: Type 'TopMenuController' has no properties in common with type 'IController'.

I don't understand the first error and Googling it has been difficult.  I'm only asking for assistance with the first error.  (I'm getting the second error due to my attempts to resolve the first).  Here's the controller:

```
export class TopMenuController implements angular.IController {
    static $inject = ["$templateCache", "Restangular"];

    constructor(
        private readonly $templateCache: angular.ITemplateCacheService,
        private readonly restangular: Restangular.IElement) {
    }
}
```

And this is how it is registered.

```
angular.module("ngApp")
    .config(Configuration.TemplateCacheConfigurator)
    .controller("topMenuController", Controllers.TopMenuController)
```

How do i modify my controller definition or its registration so our code compiles again?

(Removing the `implements angular.IController` bit removes the second error, but the first remains)

**Edit:** I found [this bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16536)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Since all of the properties of `IController` are optional, I believe the errors you are seeing are a result of the new checking for "Weak Types" in TypeScript 2.4. Check [this link from Microsoft](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2017/06/12/announcing-typescript-2-4-rc/) for details. Also check [this related Github issue](https://github.com/ceolter/ag-grid/issues/1708).

Some relevant quotes from Microsoft:

> In TypeScript 2.4, we’re adding a similar check for what we call weak
>   types. Any type that contains only optional properties is considered a
>   weak type since it provides few restrictions on what can be assigned
>   to it.

...

> In TypeScript 2.4, it’s now an error to assign anything to a weak type
>   when there’s no overlap in properties.

...

> You can think of this as TypeScript “toughening up” the weak
>   guarantees of these types to catch what would otherwise be silent
>   bugs.
>
> Since this is a breaking change, you may need to know about the
>   workarounds which are the same as those for strict object literal
>   checks:
>
> 1. Declare the properties if they really do exist.
> 2. Add an index signature to the weak type (i.e. [propName: string]: {}).
> 3. Use a type assertion (i.e. opts as Options).

**Edit:** Based on this information, a simple solution would then be to implement one of the methods defined in `IController`. For example, as mentioned by @Amy in the comments, you could just define an empty `$onInit` method in your controller.

**Edit:** For the sake of completeness, here's the full code:

```
export class TopMenuController implements angular.IController {
  static $inject = ["$templateCache", "Restangular"];

  $onInit() { }

  constructor(
      private readonly $templateCache: angular.ITemplateCacheService,
      private readonly restangular: Restangular.IElement) {
  }
}
```

Comment: You correctly identified the issue.  Adding `$onInit = () => {};` to my controller made all my troubles fade away.

Comment: Please, may you update the answer with solution? Where should I place $onInit = () => {};

Comment: @FrankModica Tnx!

Comment: In the latest version of @types/angular they've fixed the issue with the second approach. Just by upgrading you won't see the errors in your code.

Comment: @S.Klechkovski Have they? I still have to put in $onInit = () => { }; in every controller, otherwise it doesn't work.

Answer (score 10):

I also faced the same issue which I got resolved by

- implementing `IController`
- add this code before constructor (*or anywhere in code this is my preference*) `$onInit  = () => { };`

here is the full code, Hope this will give a clear view

```
module MyApp {
    export class HomeController implements angular.IController {
        $onInit = () => { };
        user: string;
        constructor() {
            this.user = "mali";
        }
    }
    angular.module('app').controller('homeController', MyApp.HomeController)
}
```

> Happy Coding

Comment: Yes, it is indeed. But for a novice user like me, It was a bit difficult to understand where to keep  $onInit = () => { };, that is why I have posted the full code for better understanding. You can see in comments also people asking where to put it.

Answer (score 0):

adding the following code fixed the issue

```
$onInit = () => { };
```