# TypeScript antlr4ts listener type throwing an error

Tags: angularjs, typescript, antlr4

I am trying to use the antlr4 parser in an angular project.

There is a dataservice class in which the invoked function looks like following

```
parseRule() {
  const ruleString = ' STRING TO PARSE';

  const inputStream = new ANTLRInputStream(ruleString);
  const lexObject = new lexer.scopeLexer(inputStream);
  const tokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(lexObject);
  const parseObject = new parser.scopeParser(tokenStream);
  const result = parseObject.file();
  const evaluator = new ScopeEvaluator();
  const walker = new ParseTreeWalker();

  walker.walk(evaluator, result);
  console.log(' result :', result.text);
}
```

A customer listener is implementing the interface exported with just one method which is enterNonGraphScope.

```
import { scopeListener } from './antlrscope/scopeListener';
import { NonGraphScopeContext, NamesetSimpleContext } from './antlrscope/scopeParser';

export class ScopeEvaluator implements scopeListener {

  constructor() {
    console.log('constructed the asdfasf');
  }

  enterNonGraphScope = function (ctx: NonGraphScopeContext) {
    console.log('Tis ', ctx.text);
  };

}
```

Pasting some snippet from the scopeListener.ts for purposes of illustration of the interface

```
export interface scopeListener extends ParseTreeListener {

/**
 * Enter a parse tree produced by the `NonGraphScope`
 * labeled alternative in `scopeParser.scope`.
 * @param ctx the parse tree
*/
enterNonGraphScope?: (ctx: NonGraphScopeContext) => void;
```

When I am running the angular ng serve, which is compiling the typescript code.
I am getting an error

**ERROR in src/app/rule-parser.service.ts(31,17): error TS2559: Type 'ScopeEvaluator' has no properties in common with type 'ParseTreeListener'.**

Below is the listener generated in typescript. (Removed contents and antlr generated comments)

```
export interface scopeListener extends ParseTreeListener {
    enterNonGraphScope?: (ctx: NonGraphScopeContext) => void;
    exitNonGraphScope?: (ctx: NonGraphScopeContext) => void;
    enterBlockScope?: (ctx: BlockScopeContext) => void;
    exitBlockScope?: (ctx: BlockScopeContext) => void;
    enterNamesetSimple?: (ctx: NamesetSimpleContext) => void;
    exitNamesetSimple?: (ctx: NamesetSimpleContext) => void;
    enterGrainExpression?: (ctx: GrainExpressionContext) => void;
    exitGrainExpression?: (ctx: GrainExpressionContext) => void;
    enterGrainSimple?: (ctx: GrainSimpleContext) => void;
    exitGrainSimple?: (ctx: GrainSimpleContext) => void;
    enterNamesetExpression?: (ctx: NamesetExpressionContext) => void;
}
```

It seems to be something to do with typescript interpretation or typing.
I am a newbie to javascript/typescript. Could you please help me out ?

The webpack / generated javascript code functions fine, but this error prevents the build from being generated.

Thanks a lot !

-Vinayak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a bit of googling about this and found this to do something with weak type handling change. More details on below link.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2017/06/12/announcing-typescript-2-4-rc/

Based on this an another stackoverflow discussion at
[After upgrading TypeScript, Angular controller registration now fails to compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44803945/after-upgrading-typescript-angular-controller-registration-now-fails-to-compile)

Below modification to the class implementing interfaces worked.
Option 1 is better as it's just a type assertion.

**Option 1**

```
    parseRule() {
      const ruleString = ' Scope: (Dim1.Attr1 * &Namset1);' +
        ' Measure.[asdfa] = ddd ;' +
        'end scOPe;';

      const inputStream = new ANTLRInputStream(ruleString);
      const lexObject = new lexer.scopeLexer(inputStream);
      const tokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(lexObject);
      const parseObject = new parser.scopeParser(tokenStream);
      const result = parseObject.file();
      const evaluator = new ScopeEvaluator();
      const walker = new ParseTreeWalker();
      console.log(' type of ' , evaluator);
      walker.walk(evaluator as ParseTreeListener, result);
        // Parse and execute the code.
        console.log(' p :', parseObject);
      console.log(' result :', result.text);
    }
```

**Option 2 - involves redeclaring stuff ?**

```
            import { scopeListener } from './antlrscope/scopeListener';
            import { NonGraphScopeContext, NamesetSimpleContext } from './antlrscope/scopeParser';
            import { ParseTreeListener } from 'antlr4ts/tree/ParseTreeListener';


            export class ScopeEvaluator implements scopeListener {

                visitTerminal = () => { };
                visitErrorNode = () => { };
                enterEveryRule = () => { };
                exitEveryRule = () => { };
                enterNonGraphScope = function (ctx: NonGraphScopeContext) {
                    console.log('Tis ', ctx.text);
                };
            }
```

If you feel this is not the right way of doing it, please comment. My understanding of typescript is not complete.

Comment: What TS version do you use currently? [My listener](https://github.com/mike-lischke/vscode-antlr4/blob/master/src/backend/DetailsListener.ts) transpiles without these tricks (I'm on 2.7.2 atm). How does your `scopeListener` look like? Is the method signature correct? What is the full error message here? Maybe you have a conflict with the `NonGraphScopeContext` type?

Comment: @MikeLischke In the angular project, typescript version is 2.5.3 . I am not sure if I upgrade the typescript version, anything in the angular project gets impacted or not. I will add the listener to the main question. In angular when I run ng serve I get that error, though the compilation goes through, but when I do production build the error prevents me from building the angular app.

Comment: I will just accept my own answer. It might help a new bie trying to work with antlr on current angular build.